# How Qt source installs forward header?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

In Qt source code, every module has its own include folder, but all the headers inside act like fake (forward) header which contains only one line points to the real exported header, e.g. `#include "../../src/folder1/realheader.h"` . When the source code get built and installed, it somehow pastes the real headers to the installed include folder. I find it a very neat way to structure code, and wanna use it in my own project. So my problem is how to use CMake (with some scripts if neccessary) to achieve this.

I looked into Qt's CMake code, but failed to locate the code to handle forward headers. I hope to find the corresponding CMake code, or minimum CMake code to handle forward header files.

---

Take *QAbstractAnimation* for example.

Its related sources locate in

- ${QT_SRC_ROOT}/qtbase/src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation.h
- ${QT_SRC_ROOT}/qtbase/src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation.cpp
- private impl (don't care)

Its export header files are

- ${QT_SRC_ROOT}/qtbase/include/QtCore/QAbstractAnimation
- ${QT_SRC_ROOT}/qtbase/include/QtCore/qabstractanimation.h

where QAbstractAnimation contains `#include "qabstractanimation.h"` ,
and qabstractanimation.h contains `#include "../../src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation.h"`.

To my understanding, QAbstractAnimation is an alias header to qabstractanimation.h, and qabstractanimation.h is forward header points to the real header in src.

When the source code get built and installed, QAbstractAnimation headers go to

- ${QT_INSTALL_ROOT}/include/QtCore/QAbstractAnimation
- ${QT_INSTALL_ROOT}/include/QtCore/qabstractanimation.h

where QAbstractAnimation is the same, but qabstractanimation.h becomes the real header located in `"${QT_SRC_ROOT}/qtbase/src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation.h"`. It's definitely not just simply copy the source include folder to install include directory. Some path resolve must be taken place by CMake or other scripts. I wonder how it works.

Comment: Could you show such a real code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @273K Sure, I provided an example to better understand my problem.